# surfaceCreated not called

Tags: android, android-layout

I put a log.d in the method, and it never reports. The Game's run() method is executed, but I defensively wait for the surfaceCreated method to return before proceeding.

Notes: Game is a Thread and
TouchPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback

```
private final void runGame() {
        savedPos = 0;
        resumeGame();
        touchPanel = (TouchPanel)findViewById(com.mysite.mygame.R.id.touchPanel);
        touchPanel.setMinimumHeight(displayWidth);
        touchPanel.setParams(this, writeLock, gemSize9, gemSize12, marg);
        textUpdate = new TextUpdate(this, d);
        gm = new Game(tok9, tok12, m, d, this, textHandler, textUpdate, touchPanel, marg, gemSize9, gemSize12, readLock, writeLock);
        initBitmaps();
        gm.start();
}
private final void resumeGame() {
        loadBGMusic();
        layout = Layout.GAME;
        setContentView(com.mysite.mygame.R.layout.game);
        writeLock.lock(); try { paused = false; } finally { writeLock.unlock(); }
}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/rel"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
   android:keepScreenOn="true"
   >
    <com.mysite.mygame.TouchPanel
       android:id="@+id/touchPanel"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       />
</RelativeLayout>

public TouchPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there something about the way this code handles TouchPanel that prevents it from being attached to the window? The method surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) doesn't get called after this code executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
@id/touchPanel
```

should have

```
android:layout_height != 0
```

and

```
android:layout_width != 0
```

for the Surface to be created in a SurfaceView.

Comment: Could you clarify this? If I put 'android:layout_width!=0' in the layout XML I get parse error(s)